# Root can resolve localhost, while normal user cannot

Tags: linux, dns, localhost

I think I encounter a weird problem:

With a normal user: when I `ping localhost`, I got `ping: unknown host localhost`, when I ping `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`, I got response.

With root: everything is fine.

Here is the content in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
... [opt out]
```

I am using CentOS (rocks cluster system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that `/etc/hosts` is not readable by ordinary users. What are the permissions of that file?

Comment: Exactly the problem, after granting the permission it works. I have no idea why the hosts file was only readable to root.